# Replacing values from HashMap in a file with Java

Tags: java, replace, hashmap, buffer, str-replace

i'm stuck on this part. The aim is to take the values from an file.ini with this format

```
X = Y
X1 = Y1
X2 = Y2
```

take the Y values and replace them in a scxml file instead of the corresponding X keys, and save the new file.scxml

As you can see from my pasted code, i use the HashMap to take the key and values printed correctly, that although it seems right the code to replace the values works only for the first entry of the HashMap.

The code is currently as follows:

```
public String getPropValues() throws IOException {
        try {
            Properties prop = new Properties();         
            String pathconf = this.pathconf;
            String pathxml = this.pathxml;
            
            //Read file conf
            File inputFile = new File(pathconf);
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
 
            //load the buffered file
            prop.load(br);
            String name = prop.getProperty("name");
                        
            //Read xml file to get the format
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(pathxml);            
            
            String newString;
            StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
            
            String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        
            BufferedReader rb = new BufferedReader(reader);
            
            //read file.ini to HashMap
            Map<String, String> mapFromFile = getHashMapFromFile();
            
            //iterate over HashMap entries
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mapFromFile.entrySet()){
                
                System.out.println( entry.getKey() + " -> " + entry.getValue() );
                
                //replace values
                while ((newString = rb.readLine()) != null){
                    str.append(lineSeparator);
                    str.append(newString.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));         
                }
            }
                
            rb.close();
            
            String pathwriter = pathxml + name + ".scxml";
                        
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(pathwriter)));
            
            bw.write(str.toString());        
            //flush the stream
            bw.flush();      
            //close the stream
            bw.close();
                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }     
        
        return result;
    }
```

so my .ini file is for example

```
Apple = red
Lemon = yellow
```

it print key and values correctly:

```
Apple -> red
Lemon -> yellow
```

but replace in the file only **Apple** with **red** and not the others key

Comment: Aside from the inside-out control flow, there is no reason to use `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` since all the work is being done in a single thread, and there is no reason to use `replaceAll` instead of `replace` since you are just doing string substitution, not regular expressions. In fact, `replaceAll` is dangerous here, in case the strings to replace could ever contain characters that are meaningful in regular expressions.

Comment: What you want to do is, in a loop over all the lines from the file: first, loop over the map and perform all the replacements on that line. Then, after that line is fully updated, append it to the output.

Comment: I have tried as suggested, but it simply recreates the file as it is. for sure I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays in your control flow order.

By the time the first iteration in your `for` loop, which corresponds to the first entry `Apple -> red`, runs it would caused the `BufferedReader rb` to reach the end of stream, hence doing nothing for subsequent iterations.

You have then either to reinitialize the `BufferedReader` for each iteration, or better, inverse the looping over your `Map` entries to be within the `BufferedReader` read loop:

### EDIT (following @David hints)

You should can assign the resulting `replace`d value to the line replacement that will be appended to the result file at each line iteration:

```
public String getPropValues() throws IOException {

    try {

        // ...
    
        BufferedReader rb = new BufferedReader(reader);
        
        //read file.ini to HashMap
        Map<String, String> mapFromFile = getHashMapFromFile();

        //replace values
        while ((newString = rb.readLine()) != null) {
            // iterate over HashMap entries
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mapFromFile.entrySet()) {
                newString = newString.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());  
            }
            str.append(lineSeparator)
                .append(newString);
        }
            
        rb.close();
        
        // ...
            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }     
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In this way it will replace all the values but it will write the content of the file for every loop. So taking the example file the output file will be from "string1 - Apple \n string2 - Lemon" to "string1 - red \n string1 - Apple \n string2 - Lemon \n string2 - yellow"

Comment: The scope file should be "string1 - red \n string2 - yellow"

Comment: This is close, but needs to do all the replacements to each line before appending it to the output.

Comment: I have edited the answer to fix the replacement per the needed output.
Thanks @DavidConrad for the extra hint.

Comment: I confirm that the code, both with and without the other general suggestions, works. Thank you good Sirs